# Need the parent div above the children, React and tailwind,

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, z-index

This motion div is a sidebar, and the menu items is a category, the category open another sidebar nested the first, but the second sidebar is above the parent, help.

```
  <AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={false}>
    {open && (
      <>
        <motion.div {/* this is the white sidebar */}
          {...framerSidebarPanel}
          className="w-[391px] bg-white absolute left-0 top-[127px] py-12 h-screen z-50 shadow-side"
          ref={overlayRef}
        >
          <MenuItem text={text.fon} expanded={1} sub={fonSubCategories} /> // children
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div
          {...framerSidebarBackground}
          className="w-full  bg-black/50 absolute left-0 top-[127px] h-screen z-10"
        ></motion.div>
      </>
    )}
  </AnimatePresence>
```

down is the MenuItem Component

```
    <div className="relative h-[63px] my-2 py-1 hover:bg-zinc-100 flex items-center text-xl text-blue-400 hover:text-cyan-700 font-semibold leading-tight ">
  <div className="flex gap-28 items-center absolute right-10">
    <div className="min-w-[130px]">{text}</div>
    <ArrowForwardIosIcon sx={!sub && { opacity: 0 }} />
  </div>
  {/* this red div is above the white sidebar */}
  {isExpanded && <div className="w-[391px] h-20 bg-red-200 absolute top-0 left-[200px] -z-10"></div>}
</div>
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXrc2.png)

I need the parent above the children element

Answer (score 0):

Did you try play with z-index?

```
<AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={false}>
  {open && (
    <>
      <motion.div
        {...framerSidebarBackground}
        className="w-full bg-black/50 absolute left-0 top-[127px] h-screen z-10"
      ></motion.div>
      <motion.div
        {...framerSidebarPanel}
        className="w-[391px] bg-white absolute left-0 top-[127px] py-12 h-screen z-50 shadow-side"
        ref={overlayRef}
      >
        <MenuItem text={text.fon} expanded={1} sub={fonSubCategories} />
      </motion.div>
    </>
  )}
</AnimatePresence>

<div className="relative h-[63px] my-2 py-1 hover:bg-zinc-100 flex items-center text-xl text-blue-400 hover:text-cyan-700 font-semibold leading-tight ">
  <div className="flex gap-28 items-center absolute right-10">
    <div className="min-w-[130px]">{text}</div>
    <ArrowForwardIosIcon sx={!sub && { opacity: 0 }} />
  </div>
  {isExpanded && (
    <div className="w-[391px] h-20 bg-red-200 absolute top-0 left-[200px] z-40"></div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: i try your solution but is the same situation, the red div is above the white sidebar, thanks btw!